# How to check Avro version on CDH?

Tags: java, hadoop, version, cloudera, avro

Is there a mechanism of checking Avro library version on CDH?

I know that Avro library depends on the dependency in the project but I have seen that there are places on the nodes of our Hadoop cluster where the libraries reside by default. Is there a way to check the avro version contained in the CDH distribution by default?

Even when we use Avro with hive, the Avro version is something that the CDH takes by itself without separate configuration(in CDH).

I want to know how to check that Avro version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `avro-tools` and that should tell you the Avro version used.

```
$ avro-tools
Version 1.7.6-cdh5.14.0-SNAPSHOT of Apache Avro
....
```

Comment: Thanks!, I never thought avro-tools would be available on the command line!